# Possible to have multiple textfields in React Native AlertIOS api?

Tags: javascript, ios, uitextfield, react-native, uialertview

Is there a way to use React Native's AlertIOS api to have an alert with multiple textfields? It seems like the prompt function only allows for one.

And if there isn't a way to have multiple textfields, how would I go about adding this functionality to an alert?

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean multiple textfields in alert? You can concatenate multiple textfields with `"\n"` and it will look like multiple paragraphs.

Comment: I mean entirely separate text input boxes - is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you would like multiple plain text input fields in your `Alert`? If so, it is not possible with vanilla React Native. If you look at the source code [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/235b16d93287061a09c4624e612b5dc4f960ce47/React/Modules/RCTAlertManager.m#L23) and [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/235b16d93287061a09c4624e612b5dc4f960ce47/React/Modules/RCTAlertManager.m#L186), you'll see that only **plain-text**, **secure-text** or **login-password** are the available configurations. But if you really want multiple text fields in an `Alert` box (without considering not-so-great UX) , you could create a [native module](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-ios.html#content) and do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33996443/how-to-add-text-input-in-alertview-of-ios-8#answer-33996521).