# UITextfield is not getting added in UIAlertController

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode9

UITextfield is not getting added in UIAlertController

Here is my code :

```
if ([UIAlertController class]) {
            UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Forgot Password" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
            UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action){[![enter image description here][1]][1]
                NSString *str = @"OK Pressed";
            }];
            UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action){
                NSString *str = @"otherAction Pressed";
            }];
            [alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
                textField.placeholder = @"placeHolderText";
                textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
            }];
            [alert addAction:okAction];
            [alert addAction:cancelAction];
            [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
```

[image]

Comment: may be this link can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33996443/how-to-add-text-input-in-alertview-of-ios-8 Goodluck :)

Comment: did you try with a message?

Comment: Yes I did tried it with @""

Comment: @GökhanAydın I tried with that also. Didnt worked out.

Comment: can u share full method where u use it?

Comment: Added full image of code.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried you code and it works normally.

The problem, maybe, is in place where you calling this code. Like, for example, it must be called in `viewDidAppear` and not in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I have implemented this on user tap action, All things are fine except showing a textfield

Comment: Don't give comment as answer.